# Help converting Rails 2 Database logic to Rails 3.1/ PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

How do I select a single random record for each user, but order the Array by the latest record pr. user.

If Foo uploads a new painting, I would like to select a single random record from foo. This way a user that uploads 10 paintings won't monopolize all the space on the front page, but still get a slot on the top of the page.

This is how I did it with Rails 2.x running on MySQL.

```
@paintings = Painting.all.reverse
first_paintings = []
@paintings.group_by(&:user_id).each do |user_id, paintings|
  first_paintings << paintings[rand(paintings.size-1)]
end
@paintings = (first_paintings + (Painting.all - first_paintings).reverse).paginate(:per_page => 9, :page => params[:page])
```

The example above generates a lot of SQL query's and is properly badly optimized. How would you pull this off with Rails 3.1 running on PostgreSQL? I have 7000 records..

Answer (score 1):

`@paintings = Painting.all.reverse` = `@paintings = Painting.order("id desc")`

If you really want to reverse the order of the the paintings result set I would set up a scope then just use that

Something like

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base  
  scope :reversed, order("id desc")
end
```

Then you can use `Painting.reversed` anywhere you need it

Comment: I think you meant ```Painting.reversed``` for the usage.

Comment: I am pretty sure that reverse part was some monkey patching I did a few years ago to get the result. Tip noted :)

Answer (score 1):

You have definitely set up a `belongs_to` association in your `Painting` model, so I would do:

```
# painting.rb
default_scope order('id DESC')

# paintings_controller.rb
first_paintings = User.includes(:paintings).collect do |user|
  user.paintings.sample
end
@paintings = (first_paintings + Painting.where('id NOT IN (?)', first_paintings)).paginate(:per_page => 9, :page => params[:page])
```

I think this solution results in the fewest SQL queries, and is very readable. Not tested, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: There seems to be a small problem with your example: NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x000000059280d8> Number of query's is looking good though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dynamic finders:

```
Painting.order("id desc").find_by_user_id!(user.id)
```

This is assuming your Paintings table contains a user_id column or some other way to associate users to paintings which it appears you have covered since you're calling user_id in your initial code. This isn't random but using `find_all_by_user_id` would allow you to call `.reverse` on the array if you still wanted and find a random painting.

Comment: So pull back all paintings using he dynamic finder and then call rand().